# An XML viewer/editor that provides XPath for nodes

Tags: xml, editor, xml-editor

I am an XSLT designer, and I find it hard to type XPath expressions of nodes manually. Is there any XML editor or viewer which can give me XPath expressions that I can **copy-paste**? I want to put them in XSL files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if its only for xpath .. one can use notepad ++ software with its plug-ins relevant to xml,

I have been using this from many days :) it works just fine :))

Answer (score 3):

XML Spy http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html

Comment: Oh no, not the buggy, way-too-expensive, with terrible "we are the best" attitude, Altova XML Spy! If you have the money it's a good middle-class product, but not-so-good when it comes to exact standards compliance for XSLT/XPath 1.0 and 2.0 (which I assume you use). Better in that respect are oXygen and Stylus Studio which are both backed by Saxon for syntax check as opposed to a closed source unfinished beta XPath/XSLT processor (Altova). And, more importantly, they come cheap with excellent support.

Comment: I like stylus studio also - oXygen not so much. Still XMLSpy is usually a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

oXygen offers you the possibility to copy the XPath location of an element and then you can use that in your XSLT. However, that is not the way you should work...

oXygen provides XPath content completion when you edit the XSLT document. It offers you the element and attribute name tests looking into the XML associated with the XSLT in the transformation scenario. You can find more details and a link to a video demo here
http://www.oxygenxml.com/xslt_editor.html#xpathAwareCC

Hope that helps,
George

Answer (score 1):

altova XML spy provides you this option .. I am sure ..

Answer (score 1):

Tools come and go and change monetization models, so take this with a grain of salt, but here's a list of some of the existing XML tools on the market

#### VS Code Extensions

- [**XML Tools**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DotJoshJohnson.xml)
- [**XSLT/XPath for Visual Studio Code**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xslt-xpath)
- [**XPath Tools**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UliWeltersbach.XPathInformation)

#### Online

- [**Code Beautify - XPath Tester**](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester)
- [**XmlToolBox - XPath Generator**](https://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/xpath_generator.html)
- [**FreeFormatter - XPath Tester / Evaluator**](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

#### Applications

- [**JetBrains - IntelliJ IDEA - XPath Viewer**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/xpath-viewer.html) $149
- [**Liquid - XPath Tools**](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xpath-tools) $297
- [**Altova - XMLSpy**](https://www.altova.com/xmlspy-xml-editor) $549
- [**Oxygen - XSLT Editor**](https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/xslt_editor.html#xpathAwareCC) $198

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the XPather Firefox Addon, from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1192/